# What defines a post as portfolio page content?

Tags: categories, page-template

I have three types of content, Posts which I have defined as Blog and categorise accordingly, Slider Images defined by a specfic category, and Pages.

I want to have content as portfolio on a profolio page similar to a blog.

My theme allows it, under the new page editor I have options to have a portfollio template.

[image]

I have chosen that template but I cannot point a post or other piece of content to appear here.

How do I choose a post to sit under this page?

For information I am using [this theme](http://www.brankic1979.com/theme/FactoryWP/)

Comment: Do you have theme documentation?

Comment: no, where will I find this?

Comment: If you purchased it from ThemeForest docs should be included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This theme probably uses the custom post type feature. Therefore you have to create a post inside this custom post type menu. The picture below shows you the label "Cars" as a custom post type. You probably have a label "Portfolio" or something similiar here.

[image: custom post type]

Another option would be, that you can set the type of a post inside the post editor screen. Create a new post and look for a metabox where you can specify the type of this post.

If this doesn't help, you should contact the developer of your theme.

Comment: I thought that would be the case but there is no custom post type on the bar. Perhaps the install files are missing this bit?

Comment: You should contact the developer, check his [contact page](http://www.brankic1979.com/contact/) for more information.

Comment: I got in touch with the developer and I have posted the response +1 for the help

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that in the page editor there is a menu to select which category is sent to the page defined by the template.

So I had to create a new category called portfolio and then add sub categories to it.

Once a post is linked to that category it is then embedded as a portfolio item.